# How to add more product data in catalog_category_view.xml?

Tags: magento2.2.3, category-view

We get **more product** related information in the `$_product->getData()` in the product detail page, but not in category page.
Currently the only data available in the category page are,

```
Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 2442
        [attribute_set_id] => 19
        [type_id] => simple
        [sku] => wheat-tortilla-spinach
        [has_options] => 0
        [required_options] => 0
        [created_at] => 2019-09-19 04:55:54
        [updated_at] => 2019-09-19 04:55:54
        [price] => 140.0000
        [tax_class_id] => 2
        [final_price] => 140.0000
        [minimal_price] => 140.0000
        [min_price] => 140.0000
        [max_price] => 140.0000
        [tier_price] => Array
            (
            )

        [cat_index_position] => 10000
        [event_id] => 
        [logged_at] => 
        [event_type_id] => 
        [object_id] => 
        [subject_id] => 
        [subtype] => 
        [store_id] => 
        [num_view_counts] => 
        [num_reviews_count] => 
        [num_rating_summary] => 
        [is_salable] => 1
        [name] => Wheat Tortillas with Spinach
        [image] => /w/h/wheat_tortilla_spinach_2.jpg
        [small_image] => /w/h/wheat_tortilla_spinach_2.jpg
        [thumbnail] => /w/h/wheat_tortilla_spinach_2.jpg
        [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 0
        [url_key] => wheat-tortillas-with-spinach
        [swatch_image] => /w/h/wheat_tortilla_spinach_2.jpg
        [status] => 1
        [request_path] => wheat-tortillas-with-spinach.html
        [rating_summary] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
            (
                [_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [store_id] => 24
                    )

            )

        [tier_price_changed] => 0
    )  

Here I would like to add few more product attribute values such as `weight`,`custom_attribute`, and so they can be viewed in the `catalog_category_view.xml` ? 

What I do now to fetch the additional data is like this,

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load( $block->getProduct()->getId() );
    $weight = $_product->getData('weight');
    $custom_attribute = $_product->getData('custom_attribute');
But wouldn't this add more load to the products listing page?  
Someone please let me know if there is a better way.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get additional attributes on category pages, Attribute must be set to "Yes" on the option "Used in Product Listing", Check below screenshot

[image]

And then you can use below code on the category page to get that attribute value like,

```
<?php echo $_product->getWeight(); ?>
```

Hope it will help you.